# How to define scope in facebook js SDK to show user interest, movies etc?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My function is :

```
function CallAfterLogin()
{
   FB.login(function(response) 
   { 
       if (response.status === "connected")
       {
           LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
           FB.api('/me', function(data) 
           {
              console.log(data);
              if(data.email == null)
              {
                   alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                   ResetAnimate();
              }
              else
              {
                   AjaxResponse();
              }
           });
       }
   });
}
```

Instead of writing on console I want show data in browser, how can it be done?
I tried with `$("#mydiv").text(data);` , `$("#mydiv").html(data);` which dont work.

`me/movies` gives error :

> You must allow us to access your email id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `scope` like this-

```
FB.login(function(response) 
{ 
}, {scope: 'user_interests, user_likes, etc..'});
```